# Do I need separate Listeners for each Thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, listener

I have a problem I've been stuck on for a day now. I am implementing a test using threads. I cannot post the code here because it's confidential but I can give you the structure:

```
class Something{
String error = "";
Listener listener = new Listener{
onError{
error = "something";
}
... 
create some threads
start threads
```

The code in each thread may or may not give error, therefor modifying the error. My concern is that, having multiple threads, it will "confuse" the listener.

Attention: the listener is not for the threads themselves (doesn't listen if the thread stop or stuff like that). The listener was implemented independent from the threads but I do need it.

Help is much appreciate it. Ask any questions if not clear.

Comment: What do you mean by "confuse", it's really hard to make sense of what your problem may be. Also if your code is confidential then there isn't much I nor anyone can help with.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that by "confuse the listener" you are talking about errors that you may get due to the listener being called from multiple threads. Just make sure that the listener is "thread-safe" and can be called from multiple threads. For instance, a listener that interacts with a variable or structure without locking out other threads may be a problem if multiple threads try to change the same structure concurrently.

If the method only deals with local variables or member/global variables that are locked for concurrency, you should not have an issue. It is hard to provide specific advice without knowing the code which you cannot share.

Search online for "thread-safe" for Java and Android and you should find some useful information. What you are trying to do is not unusual or weird: It is common practice, but you must take care.

Comment: As @Cheticamp suggested, "thread-safe" listeners to avoid two different threads attempts registering,instantiating new observers at the same time. This may create a deadlock. so the code will be like a) create a ConcurrentHashMap, also  you can use CopyOnWriteArraySet